# How do I create a systemd unit file to set the volume at boot?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, alsa

## `/etc/systemd/system/volume.service`

This is my first attempt to create a unit file.

```
[Unit]
Description="Set volume level."
After=sound.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart='/usr/bin/amixer sset PCM -- 97%'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I had to update the unit files

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

I tried starting the volume.service

```
systemctl start volume
```

## `journalctl -xe` reveals:

```
systemd[1855]: volume.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/amixer sset PCM -- 97%: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You don't need to write a file for this, `alsa-restore.service` should already exist and be enabled...

Comment: @jasonwryan That restores the level to what it was at shut down. I'd like to explicitly set the level at boot up (independent of the level at shut down).

Comment: [systemd - Giving my service multiple arguments](https://superuser.com/q/728951/157027)

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to reinvent the wheel... Save the desired settings with `alsactl store -f /path/to/file.state` and then customize your `alsa-restore.service` so that `alsactl` reads `/path/to/file.state` (via `-f`) at start-up instead of the default file in `/var/lib/alsa`...

Comment: @don_crissti  Seems like your comment is more of an answer to me. Also, customizing an installed service file-while it would work-does not seem wise to me. It makes upgrading a pain in the bum. I suppose using a modification file in a alsa-restore.d might do the trick efficiently.

Comment: yeah, that's what I meant by "customize" i.e. write your own: [example](https://github.com/johannbg/systemd-units/blob/master/projects/alsa-utils/service/alsa-restore.service) and either disable/remove the `alsa-restore/alsa-state` from upstream or have your own run _after_ the upstream unit. I'm not on a `systemd` setup right now so can't post a proper answer (I'd like to test the solution before posting an answer...) Play with it and if you manage to make it work by all means post an answer.

Comment: @CL It was just that the quotations were creating a single argument out of multiple arguments. See answer. It turned out that an environment variable trick is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes in your `ExecStart` line are problematic:

> ExecStart='/usr/bin/amixer sset PCM -- 97%'

According to [systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html):

> Double quotes ("…") and single quotes ('…') may be used, in which case everything until the next matching quote becomes part of the same argument.

This means that you're telling systemd to execute `/usr/bin/amixer sset PCM -- 97%` instead of `/usr/bin/amixer` with the arguments `sset`, `PCM`, `--` and `97%`.

Remove the single quotes:

> ExecStart=/usr/bin/amixer sset PCM -- 97%

and your unit will work.

Comment: I thought something was fishy about it *not* working. Thanks.  A drop-in modification is probably also a good option. Although I personally think a simple unit file called `volume.service` is more transparent even if some think it is "reinventing the wheel".

Answer (score 0):

## Create a Unit File "drop-in"

This thing makes it possible to change unit files without messing up upgrading (upstream changes). Because unit files should not be changed significantly (collective agreement here, I suppose), a downstream
change (drop-in) should be expected to work for a long time.

In my case, I would like to change `alsa-restore.service`-specifically the 
`ExecStart=` part.

```
ExecStart=-@sbindir@/alsactl restore
```

1. Create a drop-in folder `mkdir /etc/systemd/system/alsa-restore.d`
2. Set volume to desired level. Save ALSA state `alsactl store -f /etc/systemd/system/alsa-restore.d/alsa-state`
3. Create drop-in unit file that specifically alters `ExecStart=`

## /etc/systemd/system/alsa-restore.d/volume.conf

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/systemd/system/alsa-restore.d/volume.sh
```

## /etc/systemd/system/alsa-restore.d/volume.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/alsactl restore -f /etc/systemd/system/alsa-restore.d/alsa-state
```

## Notes

- https://serverfault.com/questions/840996/modify-systemd-unit-file-without-altering-upstream-unit-file
- https://github.com/bear24rw/alsa-utils/blob/master/alsactl/alsa-restore.service.in

Comment: `ExecStart cannot take arguments.`: arguments work, in fact the first snippet above uses them

Comment: @AndréWerlang Duly noted and updated.