# How to configure audio volume change during login

Tags: systemd, alsa, audio-volume

After a recent update, when I now log in to my system, my audio volume control suddenly goes to 100% and nearly deafens me.  This appears to be something to do with (I guess) `systemd` changing the volume when I log in, but I do not know where to start looking to configure this.

I am happy for the volume to be set when I log in, I just want it set to 20% and not 100%.

Previously I was using `alsactl` for this, and even now running `alsactl restore` sets the volume back to my preferred 20%.  So something is changing the volume when I log in, but it's not `alsactl`.

I am running a pretty plain Arch Linux install, with LightDM as display manager and AwesomeWM window manager.  No other desktop environment to speak of.

There's nothing in `~/.config/systemd/` aside from loading an SSH agent, so I'm not quite sure where to start looking.

Does anyone know how to change the volume levels that `systemd` sets when you log in?

Comment: systemd services normally saved at `/lib/systemd/system` `/etc/systemd/system` directories, probably would be a good idea to look at them by `systemctl list-unit-files | grep active` then you will probably have an idea, which service is causing this issue.
Look at this one, if you want to set a custom volume at bootup https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364945/318405

Comment: @RakibFiha: What service would I be looking for?  None of the `alsa` ones seem to be enabled.  The `list-unit-files` command is empty, nothing is `active`.  There are `enabled` services but none of these mention `alsa` or anything sound-related.  The other question is about creating a new service file to set the volume, but I apparently already have one of these as my volume is already changing, I just need to find it so that I can change its settings.

Answer (score 0):

Pulseaudio default configuration can reset levels to 100%

using Pulseaudio option 'flat volumes = yes'

to change this option:

```
echo 'flat-volumes = 0' >> ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf
```

then re-start pulseaudio:

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
```

for further information on this see `man pulse-daemon.conf`

Comment: Very interesting!  Unfortunately I don't have Pulseaudio installed so is something else in my case.